# Displaying smoothed (convolved) densities with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to display some frequencies convolved with a Gaussian kernel in ggplot2. I tried smoothing the lines with:

```
+ stat_smooth(se = F,method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 24))
```

Without success.

I read an article suggesting the frequencies should be convolved with a Gaussian kernel. Which ggplot2's stat_density function (http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_density.html) seem to be able to produce.

However, I can't seem to be able to replace my geometry with stat_density. I there anything wrong with my code?

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

fileName = "/1.csv" # downloadable there: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5j7ckmm5s9lo8j/1.csv?dl=0

mydata = read.csv(fileName,sep=",", header=TRUE)

dataM = melt(mydata,c("bins"))

myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")))

ggplot(data=dataM,
aes(x=bins, y=value, colour=variable)) +
geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 2))
```

This code produces the following plot:

[image]

I'm looking at smoothing the lines a little bit, so they look more like this:

[image]

(from http://journal.frontiersin.org/Journal/10.3389/fncom.2013.00189/full)

Comment: So what is the output that this code produces and how is it different from the output you desire? Do you want the exact same result using a different geom?

Comment: Good point! I added figures. I want smoothed lines. I tried different ways of smoothing, but it looks like gaussian convolution is the way to go.

Comment: Per your update, it would be best if you could recalculate your densities with a larger bandwidth and then redo the plot.

Comment: The `density` function takes individual measurements and calculates a kernel density distribution by convolution (gaussian is the default kernel). For example, `plot(density(rnorm(1000)))`. You can control the smoothness with the `bw` (bandwidth) parameter. For example, `plot(density(rnorm(1000), bw=0.01))`. But your data frame is already a density distribution (analogous to the *output* of the `density` function). To generate a smoother density estimate, you need to start with the underlying data and run `density` on it, adjusting `bw` to get the smoothness where you want it.

Comment: If you don't have access to the underlying data, you can smooth out your existing density distributions as follows: `ggplot(data=dataM,
       aes(x=bins, y=value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE, span=0.3) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 2))`. Play around with the `span` parameter to get the smoothness you want.

Comment: I'm playing with it, it seems to work! Thanks eipe10!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comments solved your problem, I'll convert them to an answer:

The `density` function takes individual measurements and calculates a kernel density distribution by convolution (gaussian is the default kernel). For example, `plot(density(rnorm(1000)))`. You can control the smoothness with the `bw` (bandwidth) parameter. For example, `plot(density(rnorm(1000), bw=0.01))`.

But your data frame is already a density distribution (analogous to the output of the `density` function). To generate a smoother density estimate, you need to start with the underlying data and run `density` on it, adjusting `bw` to get the smoothness where you want it.

If you don't have access to the underlying data, you can smooth out your existing density distributions as follows:

```
ggplot(data=dataM, aes(x=bins, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
          geom_smooth(se=FALSE, span=0.3) + 
          scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 2)).
```

Play around with the `span` parameter to get the smoothness you want.